# Should I use @QueryParam or @BeanParam in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am thinking of two options for handling query/request parameters:

1. Map individual parameters to corresponding the method parameters:

```java
@GET
public String blah(@QueryParam("testParam") String testParam) {

}
```

2. Map all parameters to the properties of a Java bean:

```java
@GET
public String blah(@BeanParam RequestParamBean bean) {

}
```

The second option seems more attractive as it allows the validation logic of input query parameters to be moved and decoupled from the `blah` method whose core responsibility should be to process and delegating the validation to a validator should high degree of decoupling (and also SOLID principle, right?).

However, most of the examples I see (in fact, the existing project I am working on) use only the first option. I am wondering if is there any reason why the second option is not widely used? Are there any pitfalls? Is this an anti-pattern? Is this against any best practice?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [`@BeanParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html) annotation was introduced in JAX-RS 2.0 as a *parameter aggregator* (which means it cannot be used in JAX-RS 1.0).

---

The idea behind the [`@BeanParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html) annotation is to have a Java class to aggregate parameters annotated with `@XxxParam` annotations. The following `@XxxParam` annotations can be used to annotate the fields of a parameter aggregator class:

- [`@CookieParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/CookieParam.html)
- [`@FormParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html)
- [`@HeaderParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/HeaderParam.html)
- [`@MatrixParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/MatrixParam.html)
- [`@PathParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html)
- [`@QueryParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html)

Besides fields annotated the `@XxxParam` annotations, the parameter aggregator class can have fields annotated with the [`@Context`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) annotation. For a list of types that can be injected with the [`@Context`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) annotation, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35868654/1426227).

---

I believe it's just a matter of convenience and preference of the developers. In many situations, a class to aggregate parameters is not necessary. The use of the `@XxxParam` annotations in method parameters is very handy.

But when you need to *reuse parameters* in different methods or the method has *many parameters* annotated with `@XxxParam` annotations, go for the [`@BeanParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html) approach.

---

In your question, you mentioned the [SOLID principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). But don't forget the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) :)

Start with the `@XxxParam` annotations in your method parameters and don't overuse the [`@BeanParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html) annotation trying to solve a problem you don't have. You always can refactor your code to create a parameter aggregator class if you need it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I don't understand the last paragraph. The reason I want to use @BeanParam is to delegate the validation logic elsewhere as more of the 50% of the code in a method is used for method parameter validation. Besides the input parameter validation is inconsistent across different methods - ie some methods don't test at all. So if we have a mechanism that would ensure that we accommodate all these situations that would be great.

Comment: @user1539343 If the `@BeanParam` provides what you need, use it :)