# Could not find resource for path in JAX-RS with RESTEasy

Tags: maven, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I created a maven project with archetype as maven-archetype-webapp, and then for exposing my application as a rest webservice i'm using RestEasy, however after implementin the rest application i'm unable to acces the URL created by me.
Please guide me in what i'm doing incorrectly. Thanks for reading the question.

My UserManagementController is as below :

```
package com.restimplement.btl.pl.controller;

import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.restimplement.btl.pl.dao.UserDao;

@Path(value="/UserManagement")
public class UserManagementController {

    @GET
    @Path("/{pathParameter}")
    public Response getAllUsers( @PathParam("pathParameter") String pathParameter,
            @DefaultValue("Nothing to say") @QueryParam("queryParameter") String queryParameter)
    {
        UserDao userdao = new UserDao();
        System.out.println("able to visit  user add");
        String response = "details from: "+userdao.findObject();
        return Response.status(200).entity(response).build();
    }

}
```

My MyRestWS.java is as below :

```
package com.restimplement.btl.pl.controller;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

public class MyRestWS extends Application{

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    public MyRestWS() {
        singletons.add(new UserManagementController());
    }
}
```

My web.xml is as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>BTL_PL</display-name>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/btlservice/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- this should be the same URL pattern as the servlet-mapping property -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/btlservice</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.restimplement.btl.pl.controller.MyRestWS</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

</web-app>
```

The application was successfully deployed on JBoss-wildfly 8 however when accessing the URL : http://localhost:8080/BTL_PL/btlservice/UserManagement/getUser; i'm getting below errors on jboss console :

```
14:19:33,240 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default task-10)
failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for fu
ll path: http://localhost:8080/BTL_PL/btlservice/UserManagement/getUser
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:73) [
resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.ja
va:48) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(Res
ourceMethodRegistry.java:444) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousD
ispatcher.java:234) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispa
tcher.java:171) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.
service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.servi
ce(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.servi
ce(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-s
ervlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHand
ler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.hand
leRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:
1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(
ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final
]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHan
dler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
andler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandle
r.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0
.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest
(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRe
quest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0
.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstrain
tHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [underto
w-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandl
er.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.
0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(Se
curityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
andler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.han
dleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
andler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
andler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest
(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(Se
rvletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(Servlet
InitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(Se
rvletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:168)
 [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:6
87) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

Please let me know if there's something else that i need to add to the query for more information. Also, if i'm trying to access the wrong URL.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The `web.xml` is not required in servlet 3.x environments

In a Servlet 3.x environment (like WildFly 8.x), the `web.xml` deployment descriptor is not mandatory and you may not need it in a simple application.

You could remove it and configure your [`maven-war-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) to ignore the missing `web.xml` file by setting [`failOnMissingWebXml`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#failOnMissingWebXml) configuration property to `false` in your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
</plugins>
```

### Fixing your `Application` subclass

Change your [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) subclass to be like:

```java
@ApplicationPath("btlservice")
public class MyRestWS extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        set.add(UserManagementController.class);
        return set;
    }
}
```

The [`getClasses()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getClasses--) method returns a set of root resource, provider and [feature](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Feature.html) classes. The default life-cycle for resource class instances is per-request. The default life-cycle for providers (registered directly or via a feature) is singleton.

The [`@ApplicationPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html) annotation can be used to annotate the custom [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) subclass and define the base application URI for all JAX-RS resources configured in the application. With it you don't need to declare a servlet in the `web.xml` deployment descriptor.

For more details on the [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) class, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42077836/1426227) can be insightful.

### Requesting your endpoint

Finnally, request your endpoint that should be available in the following URL:

```
http://[server]:[port]/[context]/btlservice/UserManagement/[path-parameter]
```

Comment: hi cassio, thanks for suggesting.
I had a query : 
isn't the entry in web.xml required to mention the servlet version?
or the project facet entry of Dynamic Web modules value 3.x is enough to let us know that the servlet version is 3.x?

Comment: @ParulChauhan If your container supports Servlet 3.x, like WildFly 8, you don't need the `web.xml` deployment descriptor. But you always can have a `web.xml` if you need one.