# Jersey JAX-RS ResourceConfig with Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs, tomcat8

I have a basic REST web service that works but I do have a question. Here is a brief code snip.

```
package com.my.app;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("api")
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    RestApplication() {
        packages("com.my.app");
    }
}
```

And

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>The name of my service!</display-name>
</web-app>
```

I have been digging around in the Jersey documentation at https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html and I haven't found a way to set the Tomcat display name or version. Now I can just set those parameters in the web.xml and that works just fine but I would rather set the parameters in my class that extends ResourceConfig and get rid of the web.xml altogether. Is this possible or should I just stick with using the web.xml? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) class does not aim to replace the `web.xml` file.

### What is the `ResourceConfig` class for?

The [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) class is part of the Jersey API and provides advanced capabilities to simplify registration of JAX-RS components, such as scanning for root resource and provider classes in a provided classpath or a in a set of package names.

It extends the [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) class from the JAX-RS API. For more details about the [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) class, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42077836/1426227).

### What is the `web.xml` file for?

The `web.xml` is a deployment descriptor for servlet container based applications. It instructs the servlet container which classes (servlets, filters and listeners) must be loaded, which properties should be set in the context, etc.

Since Servlet 3.0, you don't even need the `web.xml` for simple deployments. Most of the configurations, such as registering servlets, filters and listeners can be done via [annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/package-summary.html).

However, the `web.xml` is still necessary if you want to set the `<display-name>` of your web application. So far, there's no annotation that can replace that tag.

### What your `web.xml` could be like

Apache Tomcat 8 is compatible with the Servlet 3.1 specification (check the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) for more details), so your `web.xml` can be like:

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>Web Application Name</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the link. I was digging around the docs thinking I could remove the web.xml using ResourceConfig. Is it possible to set Tomcat parameters without the web.xml?

Comment: @cbohannon You still need the `web.xml` for that purpose.

Comment: Understood, Cássio. Thanks again.