# 415 Error when Uploading file using Jersey Servlet

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

When uploading a file using test.html, I get a HTTP 415 error, unsupported media type. It appears something is not working correctly with multipart in jersey. In the console of my server, I get the following error:

```
No message body reader has been found for class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition,
    ContentType: multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryFwksqvOnuCUBmh87
```

After doing some research on the web and other StackOverflow articles, I couldn't find an appropriate solution. One of the recurring themes I've seen is about registering the Jersey multipart feature, but I'm not clear on where or how to do that within my file structure. I think I'm close to a working solution, but not there yet. Here's my code currently:

**Project Structure**

[image: Project Structure]
**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cloudant</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudant-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.box</groupId>
        <artifactId>box-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.mimepull</groupId>
        <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**UploadFiles.java**

```
package wasdev.sample.rest;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.*;


@ApplicationPath("api")
@Path("/upload")
public class UploadFiles{
    @POST
    @Path("/")
    @Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
    public Response uploadPdfFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData) throws Exception
    {
        String filename = fileMetaData.getFileName();
        String UPLOAD_PATH = "\\home\\andy" + filename;
        try
       {
           int read = 0;
           byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

           OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(UPLOAD_PATH));
            while ((read = fileInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1)
            {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Error while uploading file. Please try again !!");
        }
        return Response.ok("Data uploaded successfully !!").build();
    }
}
```

**Test.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>File Upload Example - howtodoinjava.com</h1>

<form action="http://localhost:9080/GetStartedJava/api/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p>Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" size="45" accept=".jpg" /></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload PDF" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove the [`@ApplicationPath`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html) annotation from the `UploadFiles` class. Use only [`@Path`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) to define a resource class.

---

Create a class that extends [`Application`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) or [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html), annotate it with [`@ApplicationPath`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html) and then register the [`MultipartFeature`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/MultiPartFeature.html) class:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(MultipartFeature.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        register(MultipartFeature.class);
    }
}
```

You may also need to register your resource classes too. For details on [`Application`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html), refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42077836/1426227).