# what is the usage of Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, java-ee-7

What is the usage of this code line in the rest api 
`Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();`

```
@ApplicationPath("/service")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {

    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();

    System.out.println("REST configuration starting: getClasses()");            

    //features
    //this will register Jackson JSON providers
    resources.add(org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature.class);



    //more code.....
}
```

Comment: It initializes `resources` to a new `HashSet`. Are you just asking about that, or something else?

Comment: What do you mean by 'what is the usage?' Do you mean 'what is the purpose?' or 'how do I use?'

Comment: yes, how do I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Application`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) class defines the components of a JAX-RS application. Subclasses of [`Application`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) can override the [`getClasses()`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getClasses--) to register a set of root resource, provider and feature classes used by the application.

The simplest implementation possible is as following:

```java
@ApplicationPath("api")
public SampleApplication extends Application {

}
```

In the example above no resources classes or providers are registered, so the JAX-RS runtime will scan the classpath for JAX-RS components annotated with [`@Path`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) and [`@Provider`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html) and will register them automatically.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42077836/1426227) for details.

---

`Set<Class<?>>` means a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) that holds [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)es of *unknown types* (it's expressed by the `?` [wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html)). In [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) from Oracle you'll find a whole section about [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). I encourage you to have a look.

Comment: Ok cool. thank you for the support. But this part is bit confusing : `Set<Class<?>>` Can you please explain this?

Comment: @DhanushkaSamarasinghe `Set<Class<?>>` means a `Set` that can hold `Class`es of unknown types. See the [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) section of the Java Tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate you help! :)