# Rest Webservice with netbeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans, jax-ws

I have created a very basic Java Web Application with Netbeans 8.2

Here is the steps i have done:

- "File" > "New Project" : "Java Web" > "Web Application"
- I have created a Java Class by right clicking on project name. Then New > Java Classe

Here what i have put in this java class:

```
package pkg1;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

public class TestService 
{
    @Path("/test")
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String methode_test() 
    {
        return "Hello test";
    }
}
```

I have no compilation problem.
GlassFish is launched, but i got a 404 error if i try to go to /test url...

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a couple of small changes to get your code working using NetBeans 8.2, JDK 8 and Glassfish 4.1.1 on Windows 10:

- Add a `@Path` annotation on the class as well as `methode_test()`.
- Add a second class to **pkg1** named **ApplicationConfig** which extends **javax.ws.rs.core.Application** as shown below.

This is the revised `TestService` class:

```
package pkg1;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;


@Path("/demo")
public class TestService
{
    @Path("/test")
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String methode_test()
    {
        return "Hello test";
    }
}
```

This is the additional class you need to add:

```
package pkg1;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("sample")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

}
```

My project was named **DemoService**, and therefore had a context root of **DemoService**, but in your case the URL to use would probably be: http://localhost:8080/TestService/sample/demo/test

[image: browser]

Notes:

- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42077836/2985643) to the SO question [What is that Application class lifecycle of a rest service?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42077690/2985643) for more details on why you need to create a class which extends that **Application** class.
- For convenience you can set the default path to be used in the browser when testing your project:

  - Open the **Properties** window of your project from the **Projects** panel.
  - Select **Run** and set the values of **Context Path** and **Relative URL** as appropriate:

    [image: browserDefaultURL]
- NetBeans 8.2 provides a basic "*Hello World*" REST application that you can create in just a few seconds using the Project Wizard: **File > New Project... > Samples > Web Services > REST: Hello World**.

Comment: Thanks can you tell me if this is JAX-RS. I have a doubt because the import is called javax.wx.rs. Is it the same thing?

Comment: @Bob5421 Yes, this is JAX-RS, which is _"The Java API for RESTful Web Services"_. If you look at the [Javadoc for the JAX-RS specification](https://jax-rs.github.io/apidocs/2.1/) you will see that all classes and interfaces reside in packages that start with **javax.ws.rs**, where (presumably) **ws** stands for _"web services"_ and **rs** stands for _"RESTful"_.