# How to inject an object in jaxrs with @Context annotation

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, jersey, jersey-2.0

I tried to implement something like this

```
    @Path("foo")
public class Foo {

    @Context
    private BarContext barContext;

    @GET
    @Bar(name="foo")
    public String index() {
        barContext.name // output => foo
         ...
    }

}
```

But I have no idea if it is feasible or not
someone can help me
thank you

Answer (score 0):

[`@Context` can't inject arbitrary objects for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20937362/139010)

If you're looking for a general dependency injection library/framework, your JAX-RS implementation might come with one (for example, Jersey comes with [HK2](https://hk2.java.net/), a [JSR-330](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330) implementation). Or try [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice). Or [Dagger](https://google.github.io/dagger/).