# Can HttpServletRequest be null after arriving in Java REST API?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am using REST API with spring.is it possible that request arrives from UI/CURL to following API with request parameter null?

```
 @GET
    @Path(/abc)
    @Produces({ "application/xml", "application/json" })
    Public Users getUsers(@Context HttpServletRequest request)
    {
    someOtherClassMethod(request);
    }
```

should I put null check for request here or request would always be not null if its arrived here.

Comment: If we are talking about a request, then it is already exists there.

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted if it answers your question. So that it moves to answered questions list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@Context` can be used to inject [12 object instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937362/what-objects-can-i-inject-using-the-context-annotation) related to the context of HTTP requests.

It behaves just like the @Inject and @Autowired annotations in Java EE and Spring respectively.

```
@Context HttpServletRequest request
```

Here bean is created , and so can never be null

No need of null check

Hope this answers