# Getting HttpServletResponse Null In Restful Service

Tags: java, rest, servlets

I'm making tests with a **REST** service and I need to get a `HttpServletResponse` object from it.

When I call the function like this:

http://localhost:8080/wsService/api/servicetest/testify

The `HttpServletResponse` that I get is always null

```
@Path("/testify")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response Testify(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    try {
        return Utilities.getSvc(true, "OK");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Utilities.getSvc(false, "ERROR");
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937362/what-objects-can-i-inject-using-the-context-annotation) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally did it, just needed to put the `@Context` annotation to the `HttpServletResponse` object and add a `HttpServletRequest` parameter:

```
@Path("/testify")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response Testify(@Context HttpServletResponse response, 
                        @Context HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    try {
        return Utilities.getSvc(true, "OK");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Utilities.getSvc(false, "ERROR");
    }
}
```

Comment: I only needed the `@Context` annotation. Did not need to add the `HttpServletRequest` parameter in my case.