# How to find out whether a ConstraintViolation is from a JSON property or from a URL parameter?

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I have a code that gets data from the user and validates rather it's valid or not.

The validation is for the data from the **`URL`** and the data from the `JSON`.

The problem is that in case of **`URL`** the path field contains `arg0` and that it requires me to take it from the `message`:

```
@ValidId (message = "The field is invalid")
private Long field;
```

annotation of the field.

In case of `JSON`, I simply can get the field from the `path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)`.

i.e.

```
protected String buildErrorMessage(ConstraintViolation<?> violation) {
    String path = violation.getPropertyPath().toString();
    String field = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    //field = `arg0` in case of url
    //field = `field` in case of JSON
}
```

If I'm facing a ConstraintViolation - 
how can I find out if the violation is from `JSON` or **`GET`**?

---

**EDIT**

This is where I call the buildErrorMessage from -

```
public class ValidationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ValidationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ValidationException exception) {

        if (exception instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {

            final ConstraintViolationException constraint = (ConstraintViolationException) exception;

            for (final ConstraintViolation<?> violation : constraint.getConstraintViolations()) {
                String message = buildErrorMessage(violation); //HERE
            }
}
```

Comment: you can try to call the URL from the web browser first. ensure that the JSON is correct before you start using it in your codes.

Comment: Actually, I talking about finding out during an ordinary run. not testing. I want to see how to find out only with the code.

Comment: Can you please share a bit more of code and tag your question accordingly to the technologies you are using? Is it Spring MVC? JAX-RS?

Comment: As Cassio suggests please add more details and proper steps-to-reproduce if you want your question answered.

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin Done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some steps that can be helpful when implementing an [`ExceptionMapper`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) to check whether the [`ConstraintViolation`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html) is related to *an invalid parameter sent in the URL* or related to *an invalid property sent in the JSON payload*:

- Retrieve the property [`Path`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/Path.html) from the [`ConstraintViolation`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html) using the [`getPropertyPath()`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html#getPropertyPath--) method;
- Find the leaf [`Node`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/Path.Node.html) from the property [`Path`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/Path.html);
- Check the [`Node`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/Path.Node.html) kind using the [`getKind()`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/Path.Node.html#getKind--) method.
- Handle it accordingly.

Bear in mind that parameter annotations such as [`@QueryParam`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html), [`@PathParam`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html) and [`@MatrixParam`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/MatrixParam.html) can be placed in method parameter, resource class field, or resource class bean property.

---

I would recommend you to look at my implementation of [`ExceptionMapper`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) for [`ConstraintViolationException`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html) available in [GitHub](https://github.com/cassiomolin/tasks-rest-api/blob/908d34e148612f0fed9e07827bf9ae6affc05749/src/main/java/com/cassiomolin/example/common/api/exceptionmapper/ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper.java).

Comment: Indeed - the `URL` has PARAMETER as a kind and the `JSON` has PROPERTY

Comment: @Dvir As I mentioned in my answer, just be aware that parameter annotations such as `@QueryParam`, `@PathParam` and `@MatrixParam` can be placed in method parameter, resource class field, or resource class bean property.

Answer (score 0):

By GET you mean TEXT, since GET is a Type of HTTP request you send and JSON/TEXT.... is the type/format of data that you are sending to the server.

You can use the below piece of code

```
 String contentType = request.getContentType();
          if (contentType != null && !contentType.toLowerCase(Locale.US).startsWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)) {
           //Request is JSON type
          }
    else {
    //Request is TEXT 
    }
```

It checks the ContentType of the request, if it is JSON or TEXT

Comment: I need to get it from the ConstraintViolation, not the request

Answer (score 0):

If you used spring, you can get current request in static method, and check it type.

```
public static HttpServletRequest getCurrentHttpRequest(){
    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    if (requestAttributes instanceof ServletRequestAttributes) {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)requestAttributes).getRequest();
        return request;
    }
    logger.debug("Not called in the context of an HTTP request");
    return null;
}

 if(getCurrentHttpRequest().getMethod().toLowerCase()=='get'){
     // text
 }
```

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: In ValidationExceptionMapper , get CurrentHttpRequest, and check if is http get method. Because the post o put will receive json in body.

Comment: Once the OP is using JAX-RS and assuming the application is deployed to a servlet container, they could simply inject the `HttpServletRequest` in the `ExceptionMapper` using `@Context` (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35868654/1426227)). But that's not the point here. The point is to parse the `ConstraintViolation` to check whether there's a validation error in parameter sent in the URL or there's a validation error in a property sent in the JSON payload. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50365829/1426227) for details.

Comment: A possible implementation for parsing the `ContraintViolation` is available [here](https://github.com/cassiomolin/tasks-rest-api/blob/908d34e148612f0fed9e07827bf9ae6affc05749/src/main/java/com/cassiomolin/example/common/api/exceptionmapper/ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper.java).

Comment: Yes, you are right. If the kind of ContraintViolation is in the exception, wo donot require aditional information.