# Injection Context

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs

How can I inject javax.ws.rs.core.Configuration in a filter, annotated with @WebFilter. I try something like

```
 @Context
 private Configuration configuration;
```

or

```
@Inject
private Configuration configuration;
```

but that not works.

Answer (score 1):

This injection doesn't look correct: [`Configuration`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) is a JAX-RS type that can only be injected with [`@Context`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) in *resource classes* (the ones annotated with [`@Path`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html)) or in *provider classes* (the ones annotated with [`@Provider`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html)). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35868654/1426227) for details.

You could try to expose [`Configuration`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) (or the information you need from it) as a CDI bean (using a *producer method*) and then inject it in the [`@WebFilter`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html) using [`@Inject`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/inject/Inject.html).