# Get the original URI in ExceptionMapper

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I am using an ExceptionMapper in JAX-RS.

```
 public class MyException implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        ...
    }
}
```

all works. However, is there anyway I can get a handle to the URL, or the HTTP request that generated the exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject [`UriInfo`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) using [`@Context`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html):

```java
@Context
private UriInfo uriInfo;
```

Then use the [`getRequestUri()`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getRequestUri--) method to get request URI:

```java
URI uri = uriInfo.getRequestUri();
```

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35868654/1426227) for other types that can be injected with [`@Context`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use [@Context](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/ExceptionMapper-and-the-request-td7580442.html) in class and use it to get original request:

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;
@Override
public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
   String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
```